# How to stop CMake force include precompiled headers

Tags: c++, cmake, pch

I am working on a c++ project using CMake (g++ linux, Manjaro KDE to be specific). I have a precompiled header file called `cupch.h` which I setup like:

```
target_precompile_headers(Copper-Engine PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Copper-Engine/src/cupch.h)
```

However this add these compiler flags:

```
-Winvalid-pch -include /home/jakub/programming/Copper-Engine/CMake/Debug/Copper-Engine/CMakeFiles/Copper-Engine.dir/cmake_pch.hxx
```

Which for whatever reason seem to be causing massive issues. I don't know why but my project won't compile a [UUID library](https://github.com/crashoz/uuid_v4) that is using SIMD instructions when these flags are present, I am getting errors from inside the SIMD implementation for my OS (files like `avxintrin.h`, `smmintrin.h`, etc). The moment I remove adding `cupch.h` as a precompiled header to **cmake**, these flags are gone, and suddenly my project compiles okay.

Upon further digging I found out that the culprit is the `-include` flag specifically, that to my knowledge only force includes the precompiled header so that my source files don't have to `#include "cupch.h"` at the top. However I am already doing that as I need to do it for MSVC (I am building this project on Linux but I want it to be buildable on Windows and VS as well).

How can I get rid of the `-include` flag but keep the precompiled header? I have tried searching online but only found ways how to disable precompiled headers on certain files, but I still want to use the precompiled header in (almost) all my files, just get rid of the `-include` flag and manually `#include "cupch.h"` in every `.cpp` file.

Comment: There should be no difference between a force-include and a manual include at the top, so something else must be wrong. Run a verbose build, copy a failed compilation command, modify it by *only* removing the `-include` flag, run it, and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI no, I dont think there is any difference between the two, what I am saying is that -include flag is causing issues, and for me is useless since I manually include the pch in every file. What I am asking is how to get rid of the force include CMake does